# Haystack: Does RealTimeSignalProcessor updates for updates to models.

Tags: django, django-haystack

Does `HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'` updates the index when any updates to model fields take place? In case I have used fields to filter/sort/search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but **only** when you call save() method.